# when I start my computer I can see my flash drive. But when I click it...it goes away

Tags: external-hdd, usb-drive

When I start my computer. I can see my flash drive.  But when I click it it goes away.  How can I show it again.  (something similar to 'mycomputer' in windows)

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter `sudo fdisk -l`.

To mount the partition, find the flash drive and memorize its name, something like `/dev/sdb2`.

Then create a mount point with

```
sudo mkdir /media/nameyoulikehere
```

Finally, mount your flash drive with

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /media/nameyoulikehere
```

(replace `/dev/sdb2` with actual name of your flash drive partition)